# PHP - How to Solve Bad Nested IF statements?

Tags: php, if-statement

```
if($parent_id_current > 0) {
        $parent_id = $parent_id_current;
        $sql = 'SELECT parent_id FROM ' . $GLOBALS['ecs']->table('category') . " WHERE cat_id = '$parent_id_current'";
        $parent_id_current = $GLOBALS['db']->getOne($sql);
        if($parent_id_current > 0) {
            $parent_id = $parent_id_current;
            $sql = 'SELECT parent_id FROM ' . $GLOBALS['ecs']->table('category') . " WHERE cat_id = '$parent_id_current'";
            $parent_id_current = $GLOBALS['db']->getOne($sql);
            if($parent_id_current > 0) {
                $parent_id = $parent_id_current;
                $sql = 'SELECT parent_id FROM ' . $GLOBALS['ecs']->table('category') . " WHERE cat_id = '$parent_id_current'";
                $parent_id_current = $GLOBALS['db']->getOne($sql);
                if($parent_id_current > 0) {
                    $parent_id = $parent_id_current;
                    $sql = 'SELECT parent_id FROM ' . $GLOBALS['ecs']->table('category') . " WHERE cat_id = '$parent_id_current'";
                    $parent_id_current = $GLOBALS['db']->getOne($sql);
                    if($parent_id_current > 0) {
                        $parent_id = $parent_id_current;
                        $sql = 'SELECT parent_id FROM ' . $GLOBALS['ecs']->table('category') . " WHERE cat_id = '$parent_id_current'";
                        $parent_id_current = $GLOBALS['db']->getOne($sql);
                        if($parent_id_current > 0) {
                            $parent_id = $parent_id_current;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    $parent_id = 0;
}
```

I know this is bad practice .. but how to rewrite to a good function structure. I know the return will make this code more clean.. but I just don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code to function and call it in `while` loop. As break condition set your if condition:

```
$parent_id = 0;
while ($parent_id_current > 0) {
    $parent_id = $parent_id_current;
    $parent_id_current = getParentId($parent_id_current);
}
```

---

```
function getParentId($id) {
    $sql = 'SELECT parent_id FROM ' . $GLOBALS['ecs']->table('category') . " WHERE cat_id = '$id'";
    return $GLOBALS['db']->getOne($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I missed something, this looks like a good use of the Do/While loop.  Although you might need to adjust functions to make sure you progress through the result set as anticipated.

```
do {
    $parent_id = $parent_id_current;
    $sql = 'SELECT parent_id FROM ' . $GLOBALS['ecs']->table('category') . "WHERE cat_id = '$parent_id_current'";
    $parent_id_current = $GLOBALS['db']->getOne($sql);
} while ( $parent_id_current > 0);
```

Also, when debugging nested IF statements, if you loose your place, start adding comment flags right of the open curly brace and count them down as you close them.

```
IF (test) { // 1
echo $something;
IF (test) { // 2
echo $something_else;
IF (test) { // 3
die;
} // 3
} // 2
} // 1
```